# Java-Files: get specific index from text file

Tags: java, file, path

I have the following directory `server/auth/usernames.txt` and i want to read all lines and find a specific index of the string called `clientusername`

I have the following piece of code

```
File dirFile = new File("auth/");
String clientUsername ="john";
int indexUsername = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(dirFile.getAbsolutePath() + "usernames.txt")).indexOf(clientUsername);
```

but this gives me the full path of `server/auth/usernames.txt`. I want only to get `auth/usernames.txt`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `dirFile.getAbsolutePath()` to `dirFile.toPath()`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("path-to-your-file-on-your-system!");
    System.out.println(getLineNumber("SlimShady", f));
    System.out.println(getLineNumber("Eminem", f));
    System.out.println(getLineNumber("MomsSpaghetti", f));
    System.out.println(getLineNumber("doodoodoodoo....doooooooooo...dooooooo...can't touch this!", f));

}

private static int getLineNumber(String userName, File usernameFile) {
    boolean found = false;
    int lineCount = -1;
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(usernameFile)))) {            
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !found) {
            ++lineCount; // increment and get (start at 0)
            found = line.trim().equals(userName); // found it?
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    if (!found) {
        // we didn't find it... return -1 (an impossible valid value) to handle that scenario.
        lineCount = -1;
    }
    return lineCount; // found it, what line?
    
}
```

And running it with only Eminem-related usernames in my totally made-up usernames file (we get a -1 for MC Hammer... apparently we still can't touch this.

```
run:
1
0
2
-1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```